# how to change position of infowindow in arcgis

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am using infowindow in arcgis to show some information.

[image]

Here infowindow comes over my icon. 
So how can I change position if infowindow above my icon ?

Comment: would u like to add your code here or below answer fulfil your exceptions...

Comment: I used jquery to shift infowindow above Icon

Comment: great...(I would prefer to go with inbuilt methods rather than a hack) then still .... add your answer here it will help others too...:

Comment: @vaibhavshah can you please help me out at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630872/display-info-window-on-the-multiple-coordinates-on-the-arcgis-map-in-next-js

Answer (score 1):

Well, We can resolve this by following ways:

**First Approach:**

whenever you are adding info popup based on symbol size provide **offsetX** and **offsetY** to the popup option.

[image]

For more detail and syntax [please click here...](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/popup-amd.html#popup1)

**Second Approach:**

If you are showing info window dynamically using ***info window show*** method then you can configure display point dynamically.

[image]

for more detail [please click here...](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/infowindow-amd.html#show)

Feel free to add your code for better/exact answer.

***Hoping above hints will help you :)***

Comment: Hey, can you please help me out in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642934/get-click-of-corresponding-map-marker-in-react-js

Comment: @DeepKakkar I hope this issue is resolved